# Is this a legal regex pattern in C?

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match on a line ending with something like:

```
blocking=12345us
```

The pattern I tried to match with is:

```
char *pattern = "blocking=(\\d{1,})us";
```

I have tried it with only one blackslash just in case but still no luck.

If I change that line to:

```
char *pattern = "(.*)";
```

it matches fine...

I also don't get an error when I compile either pattern with regcomp().

So I'm assuming my regex is wrong, but it works fine in Python and I'm not sure what else to try. I compiling the regex with:

```
regcomp(&regex,pattern,REG_EXTENDED)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does it do if you replace `{1,}` with `+` and `\\d` with `[[:digit:]]`?

Comment: `"blocking="` wont match `"block="`

Comment: Why do you match "blocking" against "block" text?

Comment: You should probably qualify your `char*` variables with `const` if you assign the address of a statically-allocated (and read-only) string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for REs supported by regcomp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) it would appear that `\d` is not supported - try:

```
char *pattern = "blocking=([0-9]){1,}us";
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is not part of the regular expression specification according to [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

Consider replacing with `[[:digit:]]`.